# Bootstrap layout error in production rails 5 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, layout, ruby-on-rails-5

I really don't know what can I do this little problem:

I have a Rails App works perfectly in Development, my bootstrap layout its ok, but when I run my app in production, something wrong happens with my layout.

Everything was configured in assets:precompile, I just have problem with my layout when I try to open my rails App in smartphones.

Look what happen with my layout only in smartphones and in production:

[image: DEVELOPMENT ENV]

[image: PRODUCTION ENV]

Do you know what can I do to fix it?
even running rails assets:precompile
or 
rails assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
nothing change...
thanks guys!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Looks interesting, but it's really hard to debug a picture of your website ;) Can you please edit your question and add all the relevant code snippets? eg the Rails view that generates this, and the html that results? Also: what you have done to try to figure out what's going on? Have you played in the web-dev tools to see what's happening with padding etc?

Comment: Hi Taryn!, I'm sorry. l'm trying to insert my code here but when I try to save the site sad that have something wrong with my code.

Comment: Hmmm that's odd. How about you save it just as text instead of as a code snippet. i can help you edit it so that it looks ok.

Comment: LOL thanks my friend, let's try:

Comment: No way man, if I just paste the code I receive the same message... what more can I do?

Comment: That's weird... I've never seen that happen before. ooh wait - can you paste it in... then select it and click the `{}`icon (which means to indent the code)? maybe it's spewing because you're writing tags it doesn't like... but it thinks you're trying to get those tags to run as code, instead of being displayed as code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I can confirm that the problem lies in the div that has the classes: `<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">`

when I remove *all* the classes from that div, the problem goes away (though the styling looks bad). My suspicion is that you really shouldn't be mixing an `col-offset` and `col` class into the same div (especially not both of the `md` size ones... Pick one?

Comment: let me see here in my project, thanks again my friend! one minute please.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you're setting too much of an offset for such a small screen size. Try adding these classes:

`col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-0`